# How to specify the min file name suffix in Chirpy?

Tags: chirpy

I am using Chirpy in my project to minify js files. Now the minified file names are created with .min.js as suffix. E.g. If the file name is script.js then Chirpy generates it as script.min.js when Minify is set to true.

Is there any way to tell Chirpy not to add ".min" suffix to the file name when it generates minified file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Version 2.04](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/releases/view/79914) does not add the "min" to the filename.